# Test Method that returns a List

Tags: nunit

I am new to unit testing.

I have a method

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
{

}
```

How to write unite test for the above method. whether the list is returning any data?
Please....

Comment: where is the method obtaining its data?

Comment: The method GetEmployeeList() is present in a employeeService. The method is used on a Action method in controller. I need to test the Methods in "employeeService". not sure about wrting unit tests for GetEmployeeList() Method.

Comment: GetEmployeeList() getting data from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method obtains its data from a database (as you mention in your comment), then either it's an integration test, or you need to mock out the database access, which might well be pointless if all the method does is retrieve the data without transforming it in any way.